# Why if $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Q}$, then no element of $M$ is primitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Adkin's book of Algebra, p.149 it is written :

> If $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Q}$, then no element of $M$ is primitive.

If, for example, $r = p/n$ then $r=p/n = p. 1/n$ then $p/n$ is not primitive but $1/n \in \mathbb{Q}$ is primitive; so it has been written otherwise?

Comment: What is the definition of a primitive element of $M$ here?

Comment: @sheaf, $x \in M$ is primitive if $x=ax'$ implies $a$ to be a unit of $R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\frac xy\in\Bbb Q$, then $\frac xy=2(\frac x{2y})$, and $2$ is not a unit of $\Bbb Z$ so $\frac xy$ is not primitive.